# How to get jQuery to trigger a native custom event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know the magic required to get jQuery `.trigger()` to trigger a custom event that's handled by a (**not jQuery**) native JavaScript event handler?

```
test = document.querySelectorAll('.test')[0];
test.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click')
});
test.addEventListener('custom', function(ev) {
    console.log('custom', ev.detail)
});

// Custom Native -> Native works as expected
test.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('custom', {detail: 'detail'})); // -> "custom" "detail"

// Standard jQuery -> Native works as expected
$(test).trigger('click'); // -> "click"

// Custom jQuery -> Native does not work
$(test).trigger('custom'); // -> No log?
$(test).trigger({type: 'custom'}); // -> No log?
```

[codepen.io live example](http://codepen.io/sathomas/pen/zqmZPp?editors=1011)

**Edited to add:**

A bit more details on my use case. I'm developing a library that relies on custom events but doesn't itself use jQuery. However, I'd like to make the library convenient for those applications that do have jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after stepping through the jQuery source in a debugger, it looks like there is a solution. Not elegant, but workable. The trick is to add an `onxxxx` property to the element, where `xxxx` is the event name. The addition to the code in the question would be:

```
test.oncustom = function(ev, data) {
    // ev is the jQuery Event object
    // data is data passed to jQuery `.trigger()`
}
```

Note that jQuery does not add custom data to, for example, `ev.detail`, as would be the case for a standard event. Instead it passes custom data as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to create a plugin which will serve as a wrapper around `trigger` function in jquery:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    trigger: function(type, data) {
      return this.each(function() {
        if (typeof type == "string" && type.startsWith("test:")) {
          this.dispatchEvent(new window.CustomEvent(type, data));
        }else{
           jQuery.event.trigger(type, data, this)
         }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

It is slightly modified code from: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/trigger.js#L185

Assuming that you add handler as follows:

```
test.addEventListener('test:custom', function(ev) {
  console.log('test:custom', ev.detail)
});
```

You can dispatch it by:

```
$(test).trigger('test:custom', {  detail: 'jquery'});
```

The downside is that you need to prefix all your custom events with some kind of namespace.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gverwyq3/3/)

Comment: I like your thinking, but alas it doesn't really fit my use case. I'll add a note to the problem description with more details. It's the best answer so far to my original question, though.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

At the end of the webpage see:

> Here is an example of the usage of .on() and .trigger() that uses custom data in both cases:

```
$( document ).on( "myCustomEvent", {
    foo: "bar"
}, function( event, arg1, arg2 ) {
    console.log( event.data.foo ); // "bar"
    console.log( arg1 );           // "bim"
    console.log( arg2 );           // "baz"
});

$( document ).trigger( "myCustomEvent", [ "bim", "baz" ] );
```

Comment: Right, but that's not the problem. I want jQuery to trigger a custom event that's handled by a native (non-jQuery) handler.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not a magic. The problem located in jQuery's resolving procedure on **elem[type]**. Your **test** element doesen't have **custom** handler but instead has a native **click** handler.

So, your dirty-fix might look such as:

```
**test.custom = function () {console.log('custom fixed')};**
```

Please have a look at a code-snippet from jquery-1.7.2.js below:

```
// Call a native DOM method on the target with the same name name as the     event.
// Can't use an .isFunction() check here because IE6/7 fails that test.
// Don't do default actions on window, that's where global variables be (#6170)
// IE<9 dies on focus/blur to hidden element (#1486)
if (ontype && elem[type] && ((type !== "focus" && type !== "blur") ||   event.target.offsetWidth !== 0) && !jQuery.isWindow(elem)) {
// Don't re-trigger an onFOO event when we call its FOO() method
old = elem[ontype];

if (old) {
    elem[ontype] = null;
}

// Prevent re-triggering of the same event, since we already bubbled it above
jQuery.event.triggered = type;
elem[type]();
jQuery.event.triggered = undefined;

if (old) {
    elem[ontype] = old;
}
```

}